# Python combine two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given two data frames:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1],'col2':[4]},index=[0])
b=pd.DataFrame({'col3':[7],'col4':[8]},index=[1])
```

how do I get dataframe c:

```
c=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1],'col2':[4],'col3':[7],'col4':[8]},index=[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .i believe you can use the append

```
c = a.append(b,True)
```

Comment: ,thanks. But there's a mismatch of index between a and b. You solution gives a dataframe with two rows. How can I get a one row result?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a mismatch on your indices you have to overwrite them:

```
In [66]:

a.index=b.index
pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
Out[66]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     1     4     7     8
```

If you didn't do this then you get an additional row:

```
In [71]:

pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
Out[71]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     4   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN     7     8
```